4COL problem with additional constraint on the size
The task is to prove that that 4-coloring of a graph with  additional constraint about number of vertices is NP-complete.
Constraint: Each color class should contain at least $  \frac{1}{5}$ of total number of vertices.
I think that maybe reduction from independent set/clique problem can work, but I don't know how to deal with this additional constraint, do you have any ideas how to take it into account?

We discourage posts that are simply the statement of a task (and, implicitly, a demand for us to do it).  You might find this page helpful in improving your question.  Also, what does "$\ge 1/5$ vertices" mean?  The number of vertices must be an integer, so $\ge 1/5$ is the same as $\ge 1$, which seems trivial.  Where did you encounter this task? Can you credit the original source?

@D.W. I think the question asks for each color class to contain at least one fifth of the total number of vertices, which is not a trivial task.

Great.  Abel (or others), I encourage you to [edit] the question to clarify that.

For every graph on $n$ vertices you can add $4n$ isolated vertices resulting in a graph on $5n$ vertices.
The resulting graph will be 4-colorable with each color class containing at least $n$ of all vertices if and only if the original graph is 4-colorable.
